# Calling method from DoWork handler?

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am attempting to use a `BackgroundWorker` to complete a task. I have got the worker to run correctly, under the `DoWork` method it then calls another method which executes but then I face my problem: when that method tries to call another method it does not succeed and does not throw an exception and I can only see this as being something I am doing wrong with `BackgroundWorker` since when running on the UI thread for testing the methods execute as intended.

Here is where I run my worker:

```
private void btnAddShots_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync();     
}
```

Here is my `DoWork` method:

```
private void backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    int noOfShots = dataGridShots.Rows.Count - 1;
    int count = 0;

    while (count < noOfShots)
    {
        addTaskPair(dataGridShots.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), 
            dataGridShots.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), 
            dataGridShots.Rows[count].Cells[2].Value.ToString());

        count += 1;
    }
}
```

Here is a stripped down version of `addTaskPair` method that is called by my worker:

```
private void addTaskPair(string taskName, string taskDescription, string taskPriority)
{
    try
    {
        Task trackingTask = new Task();

        trackingTask.content = taskName;
        trackingTask.description = taskDescription;
        trackingTask.priority = taskPriority; 

        string trackingJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(trackingTask);
        trackingJson = "{ \"todo-item\":" + trackingJson + " }";

        string jsonResponse;
        jsonResponse = postJSON(trackingJson, teamworkURL + "/tasklists/" 
            + todoLists.todoLists[cmbTrackingList.SelectedIndex].id + "/tasks.json");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        debugMessage(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Within the above sample you will see that I call the method `postJSON`, this is where I hit my wall. Through testing I have verified that the above method runs, but the `postJSON` method does not run at all when being called from within this thread.

I have seen many references to `Invoking` when researching this problem but they all seem to apply to changing ui controls which I do not need to do (though a progress bar is manipulated using the `ProgressChanged` `BackgroundWorker` event).

I can clarify my problem more if needs be but I am really hoping for assistance with this since I have never successfully worked with backgroundworker or threading before (I am not a professional as I'm sure you can tell from my code).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, it seems that the access of the `DataGrid` components is *not* the problem. That is, it seems those statements get executed correctly, and the `addTaskPair()` method is successfully called, but the `postJSON()` method is not.

Given that, I suspect that the evaluation of `cmbTrackingList.SelectedIndex` is what's throwing an exception and interrupting the thread.

That said, the advice is still the same: keep the UI-related stuff on the UI thread, and only run the other stuff outside the UI thread. Given the code you've posted, it seems likely that the only thing that really ought to be asynchronous (i.e. run in the background, so as to not delay the UI thread too much) is the call to `postJSON()`. Presumably this is a synchronous network call, and so could take awhile. The other stuff should run deterministically and quickly.

Given *that*, here's how I'd refactor the code, taking advantage of the new `async`/`await` feature:

```
private async void btnAddShots_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int noOfShots = dataGridShots.Rows.Count - 1;
    int count = 0;

    while (count < noOfShots)
    {
        await addTaskPair(dataGridShots.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), 
            dataGridShots.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), 
            dataGridShots.Rows[count].Cells[2].Value.ToString());

        count += 1;
    }
}

private async Task addTaskPair(string taskName, string taskDescription, string taskPriority)
{
    try
    {
        TaskData trackingTask = new TaskData();

        trackingTask.content = taskName;
        trackingTask.description = taskDescription;
        trackingTask.priority = taskPriority; 

        string trackingJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(trackingTask);
        trackingJson = "{ \"todo-item\":" + trackingJson + " }";

        string jsonResponse;
        string url = teamworkURL + "/tasklists/" 
            + todoLists.todoLists[cmbTrackingList.SelectedIndex].id + "/tasks.json";
        jsonResponse = await Task.Run(() => postJSON(trackingJson, url));
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        debugMessage(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** in the above I changed the name of your own `Task` type to `TaskData`. I *strongly* recommend you pick a name other than `Task`, due to the pervasive use of the .NET `Task` type throughout the modern .NET API.

In the above, most of the code will run on the UI thread. The `async` methods are rewritten by the compiler to return at any `await` statement, and to resume execution of that method when the awaited `Task` has completed. Note that the `async` method only returns when there is finally a `Task` object to await; so in the above, the `btnAddShots_Click()` method will initially return once the `addTaskPair()` method has called `Task.Run()` and itself has returned at the `await` statement.

Important: in this context, calling and awaiting an asynchronous method from the UI thread causes the framework to run the rest of the method *back on the UI thread*. That is, when the asynchronous operation has completed, control of the execution of the code is returned back to the UI thread where you started.

It's this feature that makes all of this work correctly, so it's useful to make sure you understand it. :)

The call to `postJSON()` is executed in a separate thread, using the `Task` object that is created by the `Task.Run()` method. Since that will be executing on other than the UI thread, I've moved the computation of its URL argument to a local variable just before the call to `Task.Run()`, which variable is then passed to the `postJSON()` method when it's called in the task thread. Doing this ensures that the evaluation of `cmbTrackingList.SelectedIndex` is done in the UI thread.

**EDIT:**

Noting that the OP has commented he is using .NET 4 and not 4.5 (in which the `async`/`await` feature was officially released), I offer this slightly more awkward alternative, which still preserves the execution characteristics of the preferable 4.5-compatible version above. While one can install the `async`/`await` features on VS2010 (and IMHO that's a better way to go), this alternative allows for "pure" .NET 4 code while still achieving basically the same runtime result.

```
private void btnAddShots_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Action<Task> continuation = null;
    TaskScheduler uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
    int noOfShots = dataGridShots.Rows.Count - 1;
    int count = 0;

    // Note that the continuation delegate is chained, attaching itself as
    // the continuation for each successive task, thus achieving a looping
    // mechanism.
    continuation = task =>
    {
        if (count < noOfShots)
        {
            addTaskPair(dataGridShots.Rows[count].Cells[0].Value.ToString(), 
                dataGridShots.Rows[count].Cells[1].Value.ToString(), 
                dataGridShots.Rows[count].Cells[2].Value.ToString())
                .ContinueWith(continuation, uiScheduler);

            count += 1;
        }
    }

    // Invoking the continuation delegate directly gets the ball rolling
    continuation(null);
}

private Task addTaskPair(string taskName, string taskDescription, string taskPriority)
{
    try
    {
        TaskData trackingTask = new TaskData();

        trackingTask.content = taskName;
        trackingTask.description = taskDescription;
        trackingTask.priority = taskPriority; 

        string trackingJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(trackingTask);
        trackingJson = "{ \"todo-item\":" + trackingJson + " }";

        string url = teamworkURL + "/tasklists/" 
            + todoLists.todoLists[cmbTrackingList.SelectedIndex].id + "/tasks.json";

        // NOTE: must explicitly specify TaskScheduler.Default, because
        // the default scheduler in the context of a Task is whatever the
        // current scheduler is, which while executing a continuation would
        // be the UI scheduler, not TaskScheduler.Default.
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => postJSON(trackingJson, url),
            CancellationToken.None, TaskCreationOptions.None, TaskScheduler.Default)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.Exception != null)
                {
                    // Task exceptions are wrapped in an AggregateException
                    debugMessage(task.Exception.InnerException.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    string jsonResponse = task.Result;

                    // do something with jsonResponse?
                }
            }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        debugMessage(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Notes:

- The task scheduler for the current synchronization context is used for each continuation. This ensures that the continuation itself is executed back on the UI thread, where you can safely interact with UI objects.
- The most awkward part of this IMHO is that your `while` loop becomes an `if` statement, since the execution of the loop spans multiple method invocations.
- While `async`/`await` would normally allow normal exception-handling syntax, when using explicit continuations you don't have this option. But `Task` will wrap any exceptions that occur in an `AggregateException` instance, which you can use to get at the real exception and report it.
- `TaskFactory.StartNew()` has a somewhat subtle behavior: the scheduler it uses to run the given task is `TaskScheduler.Current`. The first time the `addTaskPair()` method is called, there is no current task, and so `TaskScheduler.Current` returns the default (i.e. thread pool) scheduler. But every subsequent time the `addTaskPair()` method is called, it is from within a task continuation, and so `TaskScheduler.Current` would return the scheduler being used to execute the continuation. Of course, we've intentionally made this the UI scheduler and running the new `postJSON()` task using that scheduler would defeat the purpose, as it would just execute synchronously on the current thread. So it's *imperative* here to specify the scheduler we want, i.e. `TaskScheduler.Default`, corresponding to the thread pool scheduler.

Without `async`/`await`, it's a bit harder to get things just right. It's syntactically more verbose, but IMHO it's still a reasonably good option, as it substantially preserves the desired, imperative structure of the code. In particular, you get to keep the flow of execution in the UI thread, making access of UI objects trivial, and forking off the long-running operation(s) only as needed.

(I should also point out that this .NET 4 version is not strictly exactly what the compiler would generate for you when using `async`/`await`. It's very similar, but not quite the same. Also, I will point out that while implementing a method with a single `await` in this way is not too bad, it gets a bit out of hand if you want multiple continuations in the same method. It's possible, but at that point I'd think the urge to just upgrade to the latest version of C# would be very compelling :) ).

**Finally…**

If after all of the above, you want to stick with `BackgroundWorker`, it should be possible to avoid the exception that's occurring with a relatively simple change to your code:

```
    int selectedIndex = (int)Invoke((Func<int>)(() => cmbTrackingList.SelectedIndex));

    jsonResponse = postJSON(trackingJson, teamworkURL + "/tasklists/" 
        + todoLists.todoLists[selectedIndex].id + "/tasks.json");
```

I.e. just use the `Control.Invoke()` method to invoke on the UI thread an anonymous method that will return the value of `cmbTrackingList.SelectedIndex`. The `Control.Invoke()` method will receive the returned value, and will in turn return it to you. Since `Control.Invoke()` is general-purpose, its `object` return type must be cast to the type you know is being returned.

This ensures that the `cmbTrackingList` object is accessed only on the UI thread. I'll also note that if this index is not expected to change while the background processing is going on (or is specifically *not* supposed to), then yet another alternative would be to retrieve the value in your `btnAddShots_Click()` method and then pass it down to the `DoWork` event handler, which in turn would pass it to the `addTaskPair()` method where it's needed.

I put this option last because I really believe that learning the `async`/`await` feature is important and worthwhile, and that while the `BackgroundWorker` class has served us well over the years, it's essentially been deprecated by the new features. But I also readily admit that `BackgroundWorker` is still a fine way to do things, and can be made to work in your scenario.

Comment: While this has benefits (and cons) compared to my sample code, it's also completely ignoring the the OP doesn't have access to `await` anyway.

Comment: @Luaan: Thanks. That information wasn't in the question itself, so I didn't notice that. He _can_ use `async`/`await`, but it's true it's not built into .NET 4. Perhaps seeing how much simpler the code becomes when it's written using the modern features of C# will provide motivation to upgrade to .NET 4.5 and related tools.

Comment: Thank you for the extremely detailed answer. Although I haven't had chance to test these responses yet so I will update when I do. But this seems to be the best answer purely on the amount of options presented. I am very tempted to upgrade my project to .NET 4.5 after seeing how simply the `async`/`await` makes things but thank you for answering with a .NET 4.0 response as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're working with the UI controls from the `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` event handler. Don't do that.

Collect the data before starting the `BackgroundWorker`, and pass it as an argument to the `RunWorkerAsync` method. Do not touch the UI from the `BackgroundWorker.DoWork` - progress updates through the `ReportProgress` method are fine.

Also, if you're running on .NET 4.5+, you might want to consider using the new `Task` pattern instead. It still requires you to collect the data to process beforehand, but it's a lot easier to work with:

(**EDIT**: As Peter suggested, the invalid access is happening in `cmbTrackingList.SelectedIndex`; I've included it in the code below. That's exactly the reason I suggested using `static` methods for the operations happening in a separate thread - it makes you think a lot more about the data you're working with)

```
var todoList = todoLists.todoLists[cmbTrackingList.SelectedIndex];

var data = 
  dataGridShots
  .Rows
  .Select
   (
     i => 
     new 
     { 
       TaskName = i.Cells[0].Value.ToString(), 
       TaskDescription = i.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), 
       TaskPriority = i.Cells[2].Value.ToString()
     }
   )
  .ToArray();

var result = 
   await Task.Run
   (
     () => 
     foreach (var row in data) 
       handleRowData(row.TaskName, row.TaskDescription, row.TaskPriority, todoList)
   );
```

Now that you're this far, you might notice that it shouldn't be too hard to make your `postJson` method asynchronous as well (there's plenty of ways to make HTTP requests asynchronously) - this will allow you to make your whole code asynchronous without blocking any thread.

Multi-threading is **hard**. Always try to work with the highest possible abstraction, and avoid any shared state. If you *do* need shared state, you need to synchronize every single access to it, from each of the threads - try to avoid that (a good practice being having the methods executing on different threads *static*, so that you don't accidentaly touch shared state).

Comment: The only time one shouldn't touch the UI with a BGW is in `DoWork`.  Every other event handler will run in the UI thread.

Comment: @Servy Right, I thought it was obvious. I'll edit that.

Comment: Ah I see, I did wonder if that was a problem but I tested whether the contents of the dataGrid was getting through and it was so I assumed it was not a problem. Is this for the sake of 'thread safe' programming? I will make those changes when I get come back to this. Will this also solve the problem of the postJson method not being called? Also, I am running on .NET 4.0 unfortunately.

Comment: @WillB Yes, the underlying issue is that Windows Forms works on top of Windows controls that always have a distinct thread associated with them. The basic idea being that making the access synchronized each and every time would be inefficient, and hard to use - synchronizing only in very specific places is a lot easier to grasp. So instead, all the UI work only happens on one thread, assuming that multi-threaded UI wouldn't help performance anyway - you can always carve out the part that makes the data, and apply it when ready in a single operation that synchronizes with the UI (e.g. `Invoke`)

Comment: The above proposed solution has at least a few problems: **1.** it manifests the entire table of data as an array before starting the operation. This is fine for small tables, but could be a problem for very large ones. **2.** more of an issue is the use of an anonymous type, which can't effectively be passed to the hypothetical `handleRowData()` method. **3.** it ignores the one expression that is probably causing the problem, `cmbTrackingList.SelectedIndex`, which is used in the `addTaskPair()` method. If I were the OP, I'd really appreciate seeing these issues addressed for this answer.

Comment: @WillB Also, note that you can use the Async Targeting Pack to get `await` support in .NET 4.0. You might want to check if that's an option for you, because it makes asynchronous programming a lot clearer.

Comment: @PeterDuniho **1.** I hardly doubt that. It was already used in the data grid, with vastly greater overhead. In any case, I was talking about the general approach - eliminating shared state. Interleaving UI code with different threads is going to give you trouble anyway. **2.** Just a tiny detail in the implementation, but fine, I changed it to be more exlicit. **3.** Well, that's why I suggested making the method static - it very quickly shows the points where synchronization is missing.